# Algorithm to find minimum number N to partition a stack's values in X subsets with sum lower than N

Tags: algorithm, partitioning, subset-sum

I have a stack with integer values objects. I want to buy a truck with capacity N( N is unknown) to be sure that I can transport all the objects in maximum X laps.

X is known. 
In other words, I have to partition the stack( the order of objects must be maintained) In maximum X subsets with sum lower than N and find that minimum N.

Can you help me with an algorithm or an idea, please?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you want to find the minimum value of N, because the N=sum(of all the stack) is a trivial solution to your problem

Comment: See for example [this paper](http://ijcai.org/Proceedings/09/Papers/096.pdf) for some pointers (Link shamelessly stolen from Wikipedia's "Partitioning problem" page)

Comment: Yes. Minimum value of N. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as you state, "the order of objects must be maintained," then we can solve this with binary-search on `N`, in `O(|objects| * log m)`, where `m` is the total sum.

The paper @hlt linked to in a comment, about multi way number partitioning, would apply if the objects' order could be rearranged. In this case, where the order is fixed, we can just try different `N`s, packing the partitions as much as we can. If the `N` we pick is too small, we'll end up surpassing `X`. This makes `N` ordered and therefore searchable.

Comment: From past experience, probably people following the C++ tag who think the question is "homework" or something. I voted up.